# Apple TestFlight reject with wrong version number

Tags: ios, flutter, app-store-connect

At App Store Connect, I have published my app, v2.0.0(17).

Last 4 days ago, I released V2.0.1(18) to TestFlight and it is still processing. I need to increase the version number because the client wants to show app update dialog to upgrade the new version.

So today I released a new one V2.0.1(19) to TestFlight again but Apple replied with the following email. I just released 2.0.1(19) but why they mention (20) and does not say anything about issues.

```
Dear Developer,

We identified one or more issues with a recent delivery for your app,
"ProjectName" 2.0.1 (20). Please correct the following issues, then upload again.
Best regards,

The App Store Team
```

Comment: Post the issues. So maybe someone is going to answer. The email you posted doesn't contain the issues in detail.

Comment: They don't mention any issues. Just that email. :D

Comment: It is happening because Enabler Bitcode is Yes. If we changed to No and upload again. It is working now for TestFlight.